# How to hook up Iannix and Ableton Live

Tags: ableton-live

I am trying to figure out how to pipe audio from ableton live to Iannix so I can alter the sound in Iannix.  Can anyone explain how to do this? or point to some documentation that might help?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what lannix is but [Soundflower](http://www.macworld.com/article/1159440/soundflower_capture.html) should do the trick if you're on OSX.

Answer (score 0):

IanniX is not an audio sequencer, it is an OSC/MIDI/… sequencer ; so IanniX control your effects/sounds hosted in another software.

Comment: ok interesting info, but my question is about how to connect the two softwares; I wasn't looking for a clearer definition of what Iannix does.